# SQL Server 2012 time and Data

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

Passed startDate (last day of the month) with time and endDate with  time. with in that period need to get last day of the month with same timestamp.

I tried this approach, but I'm getting an error. Can anyone help me please?

```
DECLARE @tmpTable table (LastDates DateTime);
DECLARE @startDate DATETime = '2005-02-05 6:23:51 PM'; 
DECLARE @endDate DATETime =   '2005-10-05 6:23:51 PM';   
DECLARE @tmpEndDate DATETime;
Declare @TIME1 Time;
Declare @time2  int

SET  @time1 =cast(@startDate as time) 


SET @startDate = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,1));
SET @tmpEndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate);

WHILE (@startDate <= @tmpEndDate)
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO @tmpTable (LastDates) values (DATEADD(DAY, -1, @startDate));
    SET @startDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate);
END

SELECT LastDates  FROM @tmpTable;
```

Expected result:

```
2005-02-28 18:23:51.000
2005-03-31 18:23:51.000
2005-04-30 18:23:51.000
2005-05-31 18:23:51.000
2005-06-30 18:23:51.000
2005-07-31 18:23:51.000
2005-08-31 18:23:51.000
2005-09-30 18:23:51.000
```

Comment: "I'm getting an error". Did you read it? :-?

Comment: I need to get the expected result. Hope any one can help me

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you think the error message is not relevant to your problem if you get such error precisely when the problem happens?

Comment: I need to add the data part with the time part. That is my requirement

Comment: Look up `EOMonth` and tally tables. No need for a loop here. Getting the time can be easily achieved by converting the `DateTime` to `Date` and `Time` and rebuild the `DateTime`, or by using `DateTimeFromParts`.

Comment: @AnushaSubashini, when someone asks for the error message to help you, add it to your question. It will increase the chances of you getting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do that is using `EOMonth`, a tally table (or an inline tally table), and some casting (detailed comments in code):

```
DECLARE @tmpTable table (LastDates DateTime);
DECLARE @startDate DATETime = '2005-02-05 6:23:51 PM'; 
DECLARE @endDate DATETime =   '2005-10-05 6:23:51 PM';  

-- "inline" tally table - If your dates are further apart you can use more than 10 numbers
WITH Tally As
(
    SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) As Number
    FROM sys.objects
)

-- EoMonth returns `Date`, so we need to cast to `DateTime`
SELECT  CAST(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, Number - 1, @startDate)) As DateTime) + 
        -- cast to `Time` to remove the date part, and cast back to `DateTime`
        CAST(CAST(@startDate As Time) As DateTime)
FROM Tally
-- don't go after the end date...
WHERE EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, Number - 1, @startDate)) < @EndDate
```